# How to get crashdumps of Store Apps when Hang

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

we have a windows 8.1 app in the windows store that sometimes crashes or hangs and we are unable to receive reports about hangs and crashs reported by the user via the store.
Collecting of telemetriy data is enabled in the store like mentioned in this MSDN-Article(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967787.aspx).

So I did a crash of the app by myself, took a look in the WER-ReportArchive(%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting) and found a .cab & .wer-file. So I think the report was sended to microsoft, but theres still no crash or hang documented in the Dashboard of the App Store.

I tried to get a crashdump via Windows Error Reporting - LocalDumps (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx), but this dump is only generated when an error occurs.
In my case mostly the app just hangs!

I also tried to configure Windows Error Report - Registry Entries (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638%28VS.85%29.aspx), but it seems most of the entries are just ignored.
I noticed WER is creating a dump-file of AppHangs as well, before sending the data to Microsoft (memory.hdmp in ReportQueue). But this files are deleted immediately after sending.

Does somebody know a way to get memory dumps and further information for AppHangs as well?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you get anywhere on this? I'm also trying to debug a hang that does not appear to occur when the App is attached to the debugger.

Comment: @Ne0 , no, I couldn't find a solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the posibility of Just-In-Time or postmortem debugging via setting registry key for AeDebug, if you can create the crash.

Have a look at:

1. Improving apps with Quality reports
   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsstore/2012/06/27/improving-apps-with-quality-reports/
2. Debugging a Windows 8.1 Store App Crash Dump
   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2014/01/13/debugging-a-windows-8-1-store-app-crash-dump/
3. Configuring Automatic Debugging https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204634(vs.85).aspx
4. Using WER: Collecting User-Mode Dumps https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx
5. Enabling JIT-Attach Debugging https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ac5yxx6.aspx